# How to pass data from a component to another component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When I click to edit I can edit but when I try to append a kind to the parent it takes the parent infoprmation and not create a new VI.

With angular dialog I made like this but with component I dont know.

This is with dialog

```
<div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="openValueItemEditDialog({valueItem: valueItem})">Edit</div>
```

This is the TS

```
openValueItemEditDialog(editOptions: EditOptions) {
    this.dialog.open(ValueItemEditDialogComponent, {data: editOptions, disableClose: true});
  }
```

And this is the TS of dialog

```
constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public editOptions: EditOptions) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {  

     if (this.editOptions.valueItem) {
          this.editedValueItem = _.cloneDeep(this.editOptions.valueItem);
        } else {
          this.editedValueItem = emptyValueItem();
        }

export interface EditOptions {

      valueItem?: ValueItem;
      appendToParentId?: string;
      planning?: number;
    }
```

But without dialog I dont know how to pass the data

```
   showChild = false

       edit(editOptions: EditViOptions) {
  this.showChild = !this.showChild;
  if (editOptions.valueItem) {
    return editOptions.valueItem;
  } else if (editOptions.appendToParentId) {
    return editOptions.appendToParentId;
  }
  this.activeSelected = this.valueItem.id;
} //this open and closes the component

    }
```

This is the Html of Service matrix row

```
<app-edit-dialog-vi [showMePartially]="showChild"></app-edit-dialog-vi>


 <div *ngIf="valueItem.level < 7" class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="edit({appendToParentId: valueItem})">Append2</div>
```

Here is the edit-dialog-vi

```
<div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="container">
</div>
```

In the constructor I dont know what to write

This is the TS file and interface what I have created for the Edit vi dialog

```
  constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>, public editOptions: ServiceMatrixRowComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
if (this.editOptions.valueItem) {
  this.editedValueItem = _.cloneDeep(this.editOptions.valueItem);
  console.log(this.editedValueItem, '***');
} else {
  this.editedValueItem = emptyValueItem();

}

    export interface EditViOptions {
      valueItem?: ValueItem;
      appendToParentId?: string;
      planning?: number;
    }
```

Comment: you issuse that you want show thae component inside dialog??

Comment: No I want a component to use not dialog anymore, so if I have an array and want to edit not to edit from the dialog but from another component because i am deleting all the angular dialogs, it is this possible

Comment: There is still missing part. Who force you to use dialog? If you don't want to use dialog. My guess is that you are using any plugin / framework which allow to edit form elements (or datatable?) inside dialogs. Can you say which is? Do you have a public URL for your project so we can take a look? Or create [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) for this.

Comment: I am using angular 4 and angular material in a project first I have used dialogs or popups because I found easy to pass data but now I am trying to not use dialogs but normally components and there to make editing or adding new array. I will try to create a project in stackblitz.

Comment: @MoshFeu I have edited my question maybe you can hep me now ?

Comment: Sorry but no. In a quick view it should work but without debugging I couldn't help you (Not 100% the with debugging I could). Maybe Angular4 expert could but I need to try to debug it..

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for the time :)

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I will try to reproduce a stackblitz but I am not good in stackblitz and new in the angular 4

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I tried to produce a stackblitz but I don't know for my case how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question well, but you can try this :

> ParentHtml

```
<app-edit-dialog-vi [data]="dataToPass" [showMePartially]="showChild"></app-edit-dialog-vi>
 <div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="edit(valueItem.level < 7 ? {appendToParentId: valueItem.id} : {valueItem: valueItem})">Edit2</div>
```

> Parent Ts

Add a property dataToPass, and set it to the data you want to send to the child.

```
showChild = false;    
dataToPass: EditViOptions = null;

edit(editOptions: EditViOptions) {
  this.showChild = !this.showChild;
  if (editOptions.valueItem || editOptions.appendToParentId) {
    this.dataToPass = editOptions;
  }
  this.activeSelected = editOptions.valueItem.id;
}
```

> Child Ts

Add an input named `data` to get the data sent :

```
@Input() showMePartially = false;
@Input() data: EditViOptions = null;

constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>, public editOptions: ServiceMatrixRowComponent) { }

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.data.valueItem || this.data.appendToParentId) {
    this.editedValueItem = _.cloneDeep(this.data.valueItem);
    console.log(this.editedValueItem, '***');
  } else {
    this.editedValueItem = emptyValueItem();
  }

export interface EditViOptions {
  valueItem?: ValueItem;
  appendToParentId?: string;
  planning?: number;
}
```

Comment: What should I write in the Child Ts in the constructor, and you can see I have changed the code

Comment: I don't think you'll need to write anything in the constructor to get the data, since they're binded to the input `@Input() data` through the html in `<app-edit-dialog-vi [data]="dataToPass">`

Comment: As you can see in the ngOnitInit I have made an If and there I see if this is for editing or for append new child.

Comment: I edited my answer to match your files, but without a sandbox to try, I'm not sure this will work perfectly.

Comment: I am trying to match with your code, if this work I will accept your answer

Comment: The edit it is working only the append it is not working, and I have forgot to write what is for appeding in the HTML you will see the udpated code

Comment: I checked my snippets again, and I change something that might be related to this : see in parent TS : `this.activeSelected = editOptions.valueItem.id` . That might correct the behavior.

Comment: that is for somethings else I have tried but it is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174727/discussion-between-faflo10-and-zhuniqia).

Answer (score 0):

To learn better i will suggest you just look at the below link. It will let you know how to pass data from Parent-> Child  and Child-->Parent component in different ways.

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Hope it gonna help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have watched this but I am little bit new in Angular